# Change remove from cart button to an image button

Tags: 7, forms, commerce

I want to change the remove-button, that removes line items from the cart to an image button representing a trash can like this:

[image]

The code I am using in a custom module looks like this:

```
<? php
function mymodule_custom_form_views_form_commerce_cart_form_default_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  foreach ($form['edit_delete'] as &$item) {
    $item['#type']='image_button';
    $item['#src']='sites/all/themes/mytheme/images/trash.svg';
    $item['#alt']='Remove';
  }
}
```

That code shows the icon instead of the text as expected, but unfortunately it introduces a major issue: now pressing the button doesn't remove the correponding line item, but wrongly successively removes the last added line-items. So when I added item1, item2, item3 to the cart in this order, then no matter which corresponding remove-button you press, item3 is removed. Next time, you press one of the remove-buttons of the remaining 2 line-items, then item-2 is removed.
What's wrong with the above code?

Comment: Can't this be done with CSS?

Comment: Yes , that can be done and an user did it: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/916348#comment-6643332 but I would like to realise it with the in drupal already implemented image button functionality.

Comment: Ah yeah, since CSS wouldn't solve the trigger problem. I see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to unset the `#value` on your image_buttons:

```
  $item['#type']='image_button';
  $item['#src']='sites/all/themes/mytheme/images/trash.svg';
  $item['#alt']='Remove';
  unset($item['#value']); // this line here
```

The line item that is deleted is determined by the `#triggering_element` in your `$form_data`. This element is determined by a function `_form_button_was_clicked($element, &$form_state)` in form.inc in the core.

It seems that when you a `#value` has been set on your image_button, every image button is detected to have been clicked.

```
  // line 2227 in form.inc
  elseif (!empty($element['#has_garbage_value']) && isset($element['#value']) && $element['#value'] !== '') {
    return TRUE;
  }
```

That means at the end of the ride, the last image button is always set as the #triggering_element, and the last line item is always removed.

Unsetting the `#value` fixes that. Setting it to an empty string doesn't, somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of unsetting the `#value` property (which works, but I find it personally counter-intuitive), you could try setting it by using the [`form_type_image_button_value()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_type_image_button_value/7.x) function.

As an example:

```
function my_custom_module_form_views_form_commerce_cart_form_default_alter(&$form, 
&$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (!empty($form['edit_delete'])) {
    foreach (element_children($form['edit_delete']) as $key) {
      $form['edit_delete'][$key]['#type'] = 'image_button';
      $form['edit_delete'][$key]['#src'] = 'sites/all/themes/trash.png';
      $form['edit_delete'][$key]['#alt'] = 'Remove';
      $form['edit_delete'][$key]['#value'] = 
        form_type_image_button_value($form['edit_delete'][$key], NULL, $form_state);
    }
  }
}
```

The [`form_type_image_button_value()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_type_image_button_value/7.x) function is built to correctly extract the clicked image button's value from the $_POST array taking browsers' peculiarities into account.

Good luck!

P.S.: Rewrote the hook implementation mildly to use `element_children()` when iterating through the line item delete elements.

Comment: I implemented your above code and now the same wrong behavior in reversed order happens: on first button press, item-1 is removed, then item-2 ans so on …!

Comment: Let me check that again, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Sorry, but sine I won't be online tomorrow, I'll have to give the bounty to the first answer because this one is working despite your one may be more elaborated once working.

Comment: Fair enough, that is AFAICT the most established approach for this issue (which is not Drupal specific). Cheers and good luck with your projects!